# Commands with Github vs Bitbucket same/different? what about git-sh?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

What are the similarities or differences in varying commands with bitbucket versus github? (I'm a github user)

I'm currently using git-sh, will this be compatible with bitbucket?

Answer (score 6):

git-sh is just modified git bash, there's nothing Github-specific in that. Both Github and Bitbucket are just hosting sites, meaning that you push/pull to/from them like any other remote repository - using `git push` and `pull`.

The differences come with the UI of their websites.

Answer (score 2):

One of the major diff is Bitbucket is free while Github is not.

Comment: this is more suitable as a comment